# WPF DataGrid Take() not working for ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, linq, filter

I am trying to bind a DataGrid to an Array for testing purposes.
As long as I am not trying to filter anything, the auto columns work nicely.

As soon as I try to filter the array by .Take(5) or any other filter, the rows stay empty, and there are only thing horizontal lines. I think it may have something to do, with the "anonymous" class generated by the Take. But this is a wild guess...

Let me show you some code which works nicely, and does what I want:

```
public partial class WindowLister : UserControl
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public WindowLister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = SystemWindow.FilterToplevelWindows(filterFunction);
    }

    private bool filterFunction(SystemWindow window)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 5) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now the version which does not work:

```
public partial class WindowLister : UserControl
{
    public WindowLister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = SystemWindow.FilterToplevelWindows(filterFunction).Take(5);
    }

    private bool filterFunction(SystemWindow window)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

For anyone interested, the Source used is from the very nice Lib: ManagedWinapi.Windows;

Any help is appreciated...
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you need a list (`Take`/`Where` etc will give you an `IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>` sequence). Try using `.Take(5).ToList()`, or `.Where(...).ToList()` etc (where `...` is your filter).